# Adding my own dependency to a quickly app

Tags: software-center, application-development, python, quickly, development

I have a paid app I'm getting ready to release on the software center but I need to add a package as a dependency. The problem is that I have to package the python module to a *deb and it is not included in any other repository that I know of. The module in question is [pygal](http://pygal.org/).

Will that work with a paid app? I am hoping to making the app open-source, so putting it up on launchpad is not an issue for me. How would I go about this? What would I need to do 
before I submit my app to the software center?

For reference: My app is made with Python 2.7.X, GTK3, and the Ubuntu Quickly tool.

Thank you for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library is licensed using the [LGPLv3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License), so you can use it with a commercial app without problems.

Now you have a couple of options to solve your problem:

- The easiest way is to just include pygal in your project. Just add it as a module. Copy the pygal folder to your project root folder and import it.
- A somewhat more complicated way is to add a script that uses pip to install it. Not worth the time IMHO, it won't auto-update, will need root privileges and looks quite complicated.
- Finally you can package pygal yourself in it's own deb. This option has clear advantages like a clean install and uninstall and a better update policy. While this is clearly the better option for an open-source tool that is going to be distributed by a PPA, it will be very difficult to use with the Software Center.

So, in your position, I'd go for number one.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by including the library in my <app name>_lib folder and modifying the library! The problem was that the library called its own modules assuming that it was in 

`/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/pygal` 

I used

`sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/module/folder')` to trick the module into importing its submodules correctly. Thank you for your help!